# Usercontrol int property bind to a null value from database

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, binding

I have build a usercontrol in asp.net, and there is a property like the following.
Everything works fine when the bound value is an integer. However, if the bound field return a null from database, it will return a invalid cast error.

change to a nullable int is not desirable because it changes the how programmer work with the control's property in code-behind.

Just wonder how these things should be implemented? thanks,

```
[DefaultValue(0)]
public int FixedLo
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["FixedLo"] != null)
            return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["FixedLo"]);
        else
            return 0;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == null)
            ViewState["FixedLo"] = 0;
        else 
            ViewState["FixedLo"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you binding this to the data in the database?

Comment: i'm using strong-type datatable and adapter. The column type is an int. so in the aspx, i have a objectdatasource that uses the adapter for the select query. Basically doing a pretty standard 2way binding after that.

Answer (score 1):

Would also checking for `DBNull` do the trick?

```
[DefaultValue(0)]
public int FixedLo
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["FixedLo"] != null)
            return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["FixedLo"]);
        else
            return 0;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == null || value is DBNull)
            ViewState["FixedLo"] = 0;
        else 
            ViewState["FixedLo"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the cast was done at the time the bound value get's evaluated, and it's actually before the assignment of the property. That's the problem i am having now. I might be wrong thou~

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the null value usign the following code

```
if (value == DBNull.Value)
```

also if there is still a problem make your property null able using the following code

```
public int? FixedLo
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["FixedLo"] != null)
            return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["FixedLo"]);
        else
            return 0;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == null || value == DBNull.Value)
            ViewState["FixedLo"] = 0;
        else 
            ViewState["FixedLo"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i really doubt it even gets to the property. It might be throwing error before that.